# Conversion failed when passing date/time object to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to add new information to a table, but it is giving me this *Conversion failed error when converting date/time from character to string*.

Here is part of my code:

```
try
{
    string sp = "add"; 

    comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comando.CommandText = sp;
    comando.Parameters.Clear();

    comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@person", SqlDbType.VarChar));
    comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@reason", SqlDbType.VarChar));

    comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@information", SqlDbType.VarChar));
    comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime));
    comando.Parameters[0].Value = obj.person;
    comando.Parameters[1].Value = obj.reason;
    comando.Parameters[2].Value = obj.information;
    comando.Parameters[3].Value = obj.date;
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    throw exc;
}
```

To get the information of the date I am using `obj.date = DateTime.Now;` is this correct?

Comment: `obj.date = DateTime.Now.ToString()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recall how or why sometimes sending a plain date/time object into SQL won't work as we expect it.

The solution is to convert the date/time object to the universal [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff` - which SQL absolutely loves.

Here's a snippet which takes from [J W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15736935/238722), which is actually demonstrating best practice:

```
const String UniversalDateTime = "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff";

comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comando.CommandText = sp;

comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@person", obj.person);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reason", obj.reason);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@information", obj.information);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", obj.date.ToString(UniversalDateTime));

// assuming connection is already open

comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Upon SQL receiving the date/time string representation, the value will automatically be converted to SQL's internal date/time value.

---

PS. I recall also trying the ISO 8601 format using the `T` as separator: `yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss.fff`. Try the version with the space, which worked for me when using the en-US SQL locale and non-en-US locales too.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `AddWithValue()`

```
comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comando.CommandText = sp;

comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@person", obj.person);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reason", obj.reason);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@information", obj.information);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);

// assuming connection is already open

comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: If I try obj.date = DateTime.Now.ToString()  I get an error . Now on the database the datetype is datetime

Comment: I assume `obj` is a class. What is the data type of `date`?

Comment: what about the data type of the stored procedure parameter?